# Excel: Function which gives location of a cell containing specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, string

I've had a look around on google but have only been able to find formulae for checking whether or not a cell contains a given piece of text, however what I'm looking for is slightly different.

I would like to search one column for a cell containing a given string. Then if I find it, I would like to use a value in the next-door cell on the same row.

For example, I could want to search Column A for any cell containing the word "yellow". If cell A17 contains the word "yellow", I want to output the contents of cell B17.

Would anyone be able to give me a function that does this, instead of a simple boolean True/False search?

Cheers

Comment: Hey @Tom ,, are U looking for Cell address of the Cell value to return, since Title of the question is different than text below !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("yellow",A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, works perfectly! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tom you are quite welcome

Comment: VLOOKUP would do this as well. In the example above, =vlookup("yellow", A:B, 2).